# HERE-API Symantec-Certificates no longer work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, gis, here-api

I am using Google Chrome (Dev/unstable Edition), specifically 
    `v65.0.3325.31 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)`
to access a freshly created  HERE app.
(It is actually just a layer in a map, displaying a few points on a map / infographics).

A link to a single tile looks like this (I've removed my  credentials from the link, sorry about that):

https://1.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/hybrid.day/12/2357/2359/256/png8?app_id=...o&app_code=...&lg=eng

In Chrome I can view the tile/image after defining a security exception.

According to [this Sept. 2017 post on the Google Security Blog](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/chromes-plan-to-distrust-symantec.html) ("Chrome’s Plan to Distrust Symantec Certificates"), Google will no longer (voluntarily) load any data from https- Website that come with a certificate Issued by Symantec (or Digicert, the company Symantec sold the business unit to)

For each tile, now I get warnings like these

> Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your
>   information from 1.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com (for example,
>   passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
>   NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

What should I do now?

More Background: [German Blog post from early Feb 2018](https://www.golem.de/news/https-viele-webseiten-nutzen-alte-symantec-zertifikate-1802-132622.html)

As a workaround I am loading the map tiles via http instead of https, but now I get "Mixed content warnings"

Is there a better workaround?

Comment: Yes, get in touch with the operator of the website.

Comment: The operators *want* users to ask questions on SO: https://developer.here.com/contact-us - ["Technical Questions? Check StackOverflow"](https://developer.here.com/contact-us)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should have been resolved after the SSL certificates were updated in the HERE APIs to move away from Symantec Certificates.